# How do you debug a react-native Universal Windows Application?

Tags: react-native, uwp

I've followed the instructions on how to set up the hello world "AwesomeProject" targetting the "Universal Windows Platform" from https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native-windows

The app is running and I want to debug. How do I access the developer tools and debugger?

The Getting Started instructions regards debugging on the [react-native-windows](https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native-windows#getting-started) project just points to the http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html which mention nothing about this platform.

I've tried all the obvious combinations of Command + D & CTRL-D to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I access the developer tools and debugger?

You can Press **`Shift` + `F10`** to open dev menu:

[image]

Based on the information in [here](https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native-windows/blob/06ff7663a7d4b970e7468af4a91cb1413fd8f053/local-cli/generator-windows/templates/index.windows.js)

---

BTW, On Universal Windows Platform, the react native has helped us to generate all [`UIElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx)s instead of web elements.

They can be seen in Visual Studio **Live Visual Tree** windows: 
[image]

See [Inspect XAML properties while debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt270227.aspx)

Comment: I'm failing to understand that how does this help in putting a breakpoint in JS files? The requirement is to apply breakpoint in JS files so that js bundle can be debugged.